# Regex: Find the lines on which the number 20 is repeated three times

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this cases, with the number 20 that is repeated three times in a single line:

`20  20 20 7   27`

and

`20  20 7   27 20 19`

I want to find this kind of lines on which the number 20 is repeated three times.

I made a regex, but must be improved a little bit:

SEARCH: `\b(\d+)\b.*?\1{3}`

Comment: `^.*(20.*){3}$` https://regex101.com/r/rFljVN/1

Comment: @Akina that won't work, given the fist 2 twenties have 2 spaces.

Comment: You have asked "the number 20 that is repeated three times in a single line" and "lines on which the number 20 is repeated three times". That's all. Nothing about spaces or another symbols between. So think carefully what does you need in practice before to ask...

Comment: What about 4 occurrences `10 20 30 20 40 20 50 20 60` or more?

Comment: @Akina you answer is simple and good, you can post it as Answer, you will receive my vote ! But, if there are more than 3 times, it must be a little bit change your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is matching exactly 3 times the number `20`:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:(?!\b20\b).)*(?:\b20\b(?:(?!\b20\b).)*){3}$`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/zb5GQ5/1)

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
                 Tempered greedy token
  (?:               # non capture group
    (?!\b20\b)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't 20
    .               # any character but newline
  )*                # end group, may appear 0 or more times
  (?:               # non capture group
    \b20\b          # number 20, the word boundaries are mandatory to not match 120 or 205
                 Tempered greedy token
    (?:             # non capture group
      (?!\b20\b)    # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't 20
      .             # any character but newline
    )*              # end group, may appear 0 or more times
  ){3}              # end group, must appear 3 times
$                   # end of line
```

---

I you want to match lines that contain **at least** 3 times the number `20`, use:

```
^.*(?:\b20\b.*){3}$
```